# Probability Distribution of X

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

> Question: Suppose that an alarm system produces false alarms randomly. The
>   probability that there will be at least one false alarm in a 60 minute
>   period is .001. Let X denote the number of one hour periods in a day
>   in which there are false alarms.  Describe the probability
>   distribution of X.

Probability is .001 for one hour and the probability stays the same for each hour right? Since there are 24 hours, wouldn't it just be $.001 * 24 = 0.024$?

Comment: If we look at $2000$ hours, would you say the probability was $2$?

Comment: To solve problems like these, you need some assumption on the underlying process.  Are the false alarms independent from hour to hour?  If so, something like a [Poisson Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) would seem like a natural fit.  But you will have to solve for the mean.

Comment: Try Binomial Distribution?

Comment: @DavidQuinn  Not so easy to set up...The OP only tells us that the probability of "at least one" false alarm is $.001$.  Presumably there could be two, three or more false alarms in any given hour.

Comment: @lulu. We are only counting the number of hours where there may be any number of alarms, (as opposed to no alarms) for which we have the probability.

Comment: @DavidQuinn: This is why i am confused because if i use binomial, the first part of the pdf equation is n choose k. I don't have or know what n is.

Comment: Shall we assume 24 hours in a day?

Comment: It helps that $.001$ is so small.  If you try a Poisson distribution with mean $.001$ then the probability that at least one false alarm appears is $0.0009995$ which is pretty close to what you want.  taking mean $0.0010005$ is better, but perhaps you don't need that level of precision.

Comment: @DavidQuinn  No....to get say $2$ false alarms over the day, I have to consider the probability that I got them in the same hour.  You would incorrectly set that to $0$.  To be sure, the probability is so low here that perhaps we can neglect this.  If, however, we replaced $.001$ with something larger then we absolutely couldn't neglect it.

Comment: But .001 is for 60 minutes. Would the probability be .024 for the whole day then?

Comment: Not the probability, the mean.  But, yes, I'd use $.024$ as the mean for a Poisson distribution.

Comment: @lulu we are not counting the number of alarms, but the number of whole hours in which the alarm may have sounded, perhaps more than once.

Comment: @DavidQuinn  Ah, you are correct. Thank you. I thought $X$ was the number of false alarms.  In that case, yes.  A binomial process works fine.  Still easier to compute with the Poisson process (though now that one is the approximation).

Comment: @lulu Ok, so using the Poisson distribution, the pdf is $$\frac{(mean^k)(e^-mean)}{k!}$$ and in my case, mean is .024 and k is 24, right?

Comment: @lulu the Poisson approximation is OK but not that accurate when $np$ is as small as this

Comment: @DavidQuinn  let's see...for $X=0$ Poisson gives $0.97628571$, binom gives $0.976273987$.  For $X=1$ the pair is $(0.023430857, 0.02345403)$.  For $X=2$ it is $(0.00028117,0.000269991)$.  And then effectively $0$.  But, yes.  the computational difficulty of the binomial isn't all that bad, really.  So, I agree:  that's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of the number of hours $X$ when the alarm sounds at least once in that hour is Binomial with parameters $n=24$ presumably and $p=0.001$

If instead you are interested in $Y$ the number of times the alarm sounds in a given day then it is a Poisson distribution with parameter $24\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is given by$$1-e^{-\lambda}=0.001$$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I computed the PDF for binomial and poisson and got 1 as result for both.

Comment: The PDFs of the Binomial and Poisson distributions are given by the standard formulae, so I still don't know what you mean by "got 1 as a result for both"

Comment: I wrote sum(dbinom(0:24, 24, .024) and ppois(24, .024) in R and got 1 as the output.

Comment: Computing manually with a Poisson's PDF formula, using .024 as λ and 24 as k, gives me 2.09e^-63.

Comment: Oh ok. I used this exact formula $(e^-λ)(λ^k)/k!$ with λ=.024 and k=24 and got 2.09e^-63 as the answer. Is that the PDF then?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to calculate? The PDF is the formula itself, not the numerical result of applying the formula